# Swift Framework returns 'ambiguous use of' method extension in lldb

Tags: swift, frameworks, lldb

I've upgraded to Xcode 11 & swift 5, and hit an an issue with method extensions when they are made available through a framework. More specifically, in a project structured like this:

```
-> Main Project
-> Framework created from sources in 'Main Project'
-> Subproject using the above Framework (Sources packaged in the framework are not visible to the sub-project)
```

Everything compiles and runs fine, but when running debug sessions on the subproject, all extensions in 'Framework' return `error: ambiguous use of` when invoked from the lldb command line. Here is a code sample to give an idea:

Create a macOs command line project, and add a new target, 'MagicFramework', and in a file Spells.swift (make sure the file is visible to Main & MagicFramework)

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    public func castSpell() -> String {
        return "✨ " + self
    }
}
```

Then create a subproject 'Wizard', and in a file wizard.swift (visible to Wizard only):

```
import Foundation
import MagicFramework


public class Tadaa {

    public func magic(spell:String) -> String {
        return spell.castSpell()
    }
}
```

in Wizard's main.swift file, add:

```
import Foundation

let aa = Tadaa().magic(spell: "this is magic")

print(aa)
```

You should have the following structure:

```
-> Main project
----> MagicFramework
----> Wizard subproject
```

then build&run 'Wizard' sub, with a break point on `spell.castSpell()` in `Tadaa`. At the lldb prompt, type:

```
(lldb)po spell.castSpell()
error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: ambiguous use of 'castSpell()'
spell.castSpell()
```

why?? This problem didn't occur with Xcode 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my humble opinion, this can only be a bug.

If I set up the example you are giving in your question, I can reproduce the problem.

On the breakpoint, I get

```
(lldb) po spell.castSpell()
error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: ambiguous use of 'castSpell()'
spell.castSpell()
^
```

just as you described.

However, if I look up the function `castSpell` in lldb, I get:

```
(lldb) image lookup -vn castSpell
1 match found in /Users/lameyl01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Main-dsjbnoyousgzmrdnqxtxoeyeyzpv/Build/Products/Debug/MagicFramework.framework/Versions/A/MagicFramework:
        Address: MagicFramework[0x0000000000000ab0] (MagicFramework.__TEXT.__text + 0)
        Summary: MagicFramework`(extension in MagicFramework):Swift.String.castSpell() -> Swift.String at Spells.swift:12
         Module: file = "/Users/lameyl01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Main-dsjbnoyousgzmrdnqxtxoeyeyzpv/Build/Products/Debug/MagicFramework.framework/Versions/A/MagicFramework", arch = "x86_64"
    CompileUnit: id = {0x00000000}, file = "/Users/lameyl01/tmp/Main/MagicFramework/Spells.swift", language = "swift"
       Function: id = {0x100000038}, name = "(extension in MagicFramework):Swift.String.castSpell() -> Swift.String", mangled = "$sSS14MagicFrameworkE9castSpellSSyF", range = [0x000000010033fab0-0x000000010033fb21)
       FuncType: id = {0x100000038}, byte-size = 8, decl = Spells.swift:12, compiler_type = "() -> ()"
         Blocks: id = {0x100000038}, range = [0x10033fab0-0x10033fb21)
      LineEntry: [0x000000010033fab0-0x000000010033fabf): /Users/lameyl01/tmp/Main/MagicFramework/Spells.swift:12
         Symbol: id = {0x00000005}, range = [0x000000010033fab0-0x000000010033fb21), name="(extension in MagicFramework):Swift.String.castSpell() -> Swift.String", mangled="$sSS14MagicFrameworkE9castSpellSSyF"
       Variable: id = {0x100000055}, name = "self", type = "Swift.String", location = DW_OP_fbreg(-16), decl = Spells.swift:12
```

So that means that lldb has found exactly one match: The extension in the `MagicFramework` library. So there is no reason why this should be ambiguous.

For the sake of completeness I also checked the type of the variable `spell` as llbd sees it:

```
(lldb) frame variable spell
(String) spell = "this is magic"
```

So to summarize:
lldb *knows* the type is String. It *knows* that there is a function `castSpell` defined in the extension and it knows of exactly one implementation of said function. But still it shows the error message.

So unless I'm missing something essential here, this must be a lldb bug.

Comment: Sounds about right :) thanks a lot for the details! Do you know is there's a way to work around it?

Comment: Sorry Alex, no idea how to work around this for a dynamic lib. But if you can make your MagicFramework a static library then this should be no issue (Mach-O Type in Build Settings for the target, make sure to run Product->Clean Build Folder after changing this setting)

Comment: @Alex and Lutz Thanks for this question and answer.  I found a horrible work around, but a work around none-the-less.  I temporarily added a class D with static methods that call down to the extension's methods (taking the object as a parameter) and then call the extension from there; which will get me by until this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my extension. In my situation that is a single function that I am using a lot while debugging so I have just created a global function that in your case would just accept the string and call that extension inside. Really similar to what @aepryus has pointed out in the comment to the first answer.

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    public func castSpell() -> String {
        return "✨ " + self
    }
}

func castSpell(_ string: String) -> String {
    return string.castSpell()
}
```

Then use it like that:

```
(lldb) po castSpell("this is magic")
"✨ this is magic"

(lldb)
```