# Swift linking error: type metadata accessor for Module.Class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, compiler-errors

While working in `Swift` project, I have two modules, let's say

1. `Base`
2. `Feature`

`Base` has a `SHService` class from where I am calling a function of `Feature` module (of class `SHCommon`). Feature module is building without error but `Base` raises error in linking phase.

### Snapshot of workspace:

[image]

### Base.SHService

```
import Foundation
import Feature

class SHService {

    public func printMe(printString: String){
        SHCommon().printMe(printString: printString)
    }
}
```

### Feature.SHCommon

```
import Foundation

public class SHCommon {

    public init(){}
    public func printMe(printString: String) {
        print(printString)
    }
}
```

### Link error:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please send me demo zip file. i will try solve this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot I tried to replicate this setup and got the same problem (I have to say that error message is a bit cryptic). So the problem is that you have two iOS app projects inside workspace. And while iOS app *is* a swift module, it is impossible to import one iOS app inside another one. What you can do, though, is to convert your `Feature` into framework, and then import that framework into `Base` app. Or extract `SHCommon` class into framework that both `Feature` and `Base` will import.

More about frameworks: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html

Comment: What if I want to manage two modules which have their own view controllers? In that case a framework cannot have visible view controller right? how to deal with the situation?

Comment: Yes, framework can't display view controller just because it wants. But view controller is just an object of some class. And as such, can be imported from framework by an app, and added to view hierarchy.

Comment: So `AppViewController` can import some framework, load `FrameworkViewController` and push it to it's navigation controller, or present it modally. Or you can have all your UI in some framework and then `AppDelegate` can set `FrameworkViewController` as `rootViewController` of main `UIWindow`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error after a long I found the solution that I had to add the not linked framework (library) to any `target` you important at `General` -> `Frameworks and Libraries`

Answer (score 5):

**Swift linking error: type metadata accessor**

```
error: type metadata accessor for Module.Class
```

I got this error in Xcode test target. Solution was:

```
Test target -> General -> select <app> in Host Application -> Allow testing Host Application APIs
```

Answer (score 4):

I hope I'm getting this right but if I understand it correctly from your screenshot you seem to have two applications (projects with Mach-O Type: executable) in your workspace.

Is this so in your setup? Because that would present a problem: You generally can't import code from one application into the other.

You need to make "Feature" a *Framework* or *Library* rather than an app. Then you need to add it under "Frameworks and Libraries" on the General tab in your Base build target settings.

After that, all should be ok.

Answer (score 3):

If the number of common files & classes is small, there's an easier solution (following up on @Lutz and @twealm) which will not require to convert Feature into a Framework.

- 1 Create a folder '/path/to/Sources/common/'
- 2 Put your file SHSCommon.swift (and whatever is ...common) in there
- 3 Remove that file from your project Feature
- 4 Add the folder [...]/common to both Feature and Base (note:link it, do not copy them so that both project see the same files)

If you plan to have a large number of 'common' files & classes, @Lutz and @twealm solution is the only way forward due to the cost of indexing.

Also, there's a bug in lldb-1100.0.28.19 and above, which affects Frameworks & Foundation Classes extensions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705591/swift-framework-returns-ambiguous-use-of-method-extension-in-lldb/58950130?noredirect=1#comment104168135_58950130)

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue when working on my Swift Package (`Package.swift` file).

In my case, in my `Package.swift` file, I simply did not list a local target (which I was `import`'ing) as dependency for my test target. For example, in my `.targets([])`, I was missing the target dependency for the test:

```
        .target(name: "Internal", dependencies: [
                    "Core",
                    .product(name: "Logging", package: "swift-log")
        ]),
        .target(name: "Core", dependencies: [
                    .product(name: "Logging", package: "swift-log")
        ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "InternalTests",
            dependencies: [
                "Internal", // <== I was missing this!
                "Core",
               .product(name: "Logging", package: "swift-log")
            ]),
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run into

```
Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for <module_name>.<file_name>
Undefined symbol: <module_name>.<file_name>.<function_name>() -> ()
```

The fix was just to add necessary files into binary via `Target Membership`/`Build Phases -> Compile Sources`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217378/4770877)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with two steps:

1. run Product -> Archive

This didn't solve the problem, but gave me a way better error message.

2. In my case, one of my targets was missing a Swift package (Under General -> Frameweorks, Libraries, and Embedded Content)

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the Build Configuration as "Release" for Run option for all the frameworks in a project solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with
import Feature.

What it seems like to me is that the library is written in 32bit and you are compiling for both 32bit and 64bit.
Either you need whoever wrote the library to make it compatible for 64bit
or
you need to remove the 64bit architectures from your build settings.

Comment: There is no library. Please go through my code. I just make two projects (modules) myself. Feature and Base are my own code.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the first image. Do both the projects have the 64bit architectures in their build settings?

Comment: Yes off course. I just created both empty projects. No change in settings.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the project with me? maybe it will be easier for me to help as I am unable to recreate the issue.